# Given that $f(0)=1$ and $f(n+1)=2f(n)$, let $F(n)=\sum_{i=0}^n f(i)$. Prove that $F(n)+1=f(n+1)$ using mathematical induction.

Tags: summation, induction

$f(0)=1$ and $f(n+1)=2f(n)$

$F(n)=\sum_{i=0}^n f(i)$

Prove that $F(n)+1=f(n+1)$.

First, I tried to find the base case using $n=0$, letting $P(n)$ be the proposition $F(n)=(n(n+1))/2$.
I tried to check if $P(0)$=True but I'm not too sure where to go from this. Since the given $f(0)=1$ and $F(0)=(0(0+1))/2=0$, it does not prove that $P(0)$ is true.

Please let me know if you can lead me into the right direction.

EDIT: I am supposed to use the sums of powers for this problem so (n(n+1))/2 should be correct. I proved the base case but now I am unsure how to move on with setting n=k+1.

Comment: $F(1)+1=2+1\ne f(2)=4$

Comment: Perhaps you meant the sum from *0* to $n$?

Comment: @JoshuaWang Hi, yes! I copied the code for the summation symbol online and forgot to change to i=0. It's currently edited.

Comment: First, we do not have $F(n) = n(n+1)/2$. You should use the definition directly. Second, we should get $F(0) = 0$ because of empty summation. This actually proves $P(0)$ since $F(0)+1 = f(0)$.

Answer (score 2):

To prove: $F(n) + 1 = f(n+1).$

Base case: $n = 0$

$f(1) = 2 \times f(0) = 2.$ 
$F(0) + 1 = [1] + 1 = 2.$ 
Base case checks.

Inductively assume assertion true for $n = N$.

Then $F(N) + 1 = f(N+1).$

Also, $F(N+1) = \sum_{i=0}^{(N+1)} f(i) = \sum_{i=0}^N f(i) + f(N+1) = F(N) + f(N+1).$

Therefore, $F(N+1) = F(N) + f(N+1) = 2\times F(N) + 1.$

Therefore, $F(N+1) + 1 = 2 \times[F(N) + 1] = 2\times f(N+1) = f(N+2).$

Comment: Hi, I'm confused on how you got F(N+1) = F(N)+f(N+1). Can you clarify for me? Thank you!

Comment: @Killua answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

you just need to use the definitions for $f(n)$ and $F(n)$ and then manipulate the sumation implied by $F(n)$. First,

\begin{align}
F(n) & = f(0) + f(1) + ... + f(n) \\ 
&= f(0) + f(0 + 1) + f(1 + 1) + ...+ f((n-1) +1) \\
&= f(0) + 2f(0) + 2f(1) + ...+2f(n-1)
\end{align}

If we use the definition given originally for $F(\cdot)$ and substract it to the third equallity above, we get:
\begin{align}
0 &= F(n) - F(n)\\
&= f(0) + 2f(0) - f(0) + 2f(1) - f(1) + ...+2f(n-1) - f(n-1) - f(n) \\
\end{align}
Then
\begin{align}
f(n) &= f(0) + 2f(0) - f(0) + 2f(1) - f(1) + ...+2f(n-1) - f(n-1) \\
&= f(0) + f(0) + f(1) + f(2) + ...+f(n-1)\\
&= f(0) + F(n-1) \\
&= 1 + F(n-1)
\end{align}

Since $n$ is arbitrary, we can use the change of variable $n \to n+1$ to get $f(n+1) = 1 +F(n)$.

**Edit:**
I solved without using induction. So to answer the question as asked I'm adding a proof by induction:

1. First step: we check for a base case (this is easy).
2. Second step: we declare our inductive hypostesis, i.e. $F(n) + 1 = f(n+1)$ for some $n$.
3. We prove our claim for $n+1$:

We first note that $F(n+1) = F(n) + f(n+1)$, then we use our hypotesis for $F(n)$ to get:
$$ 
\begin{aligned}
F(n+1) &= f(n+1) - 1 + f(n+1) \\
&= 2f(n+1) -1
\end{aligned}
$$
Since by definition $f(n+1) = 2f(n)$ we get that $f(n+2) = 2f(n+1)$ so we have:
$$
F(n+1) + 1 = f(n+2)
$$
Which ends the proof by induction. I hope it helps!

Comment: Hi, I'm confused on how you got F(n+1) = F(n)+f(n+1). Can you clarify for me? Thank you!

Comment: It's a very simple trick $F(n+1) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n+1} f(i) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n} f(i) + f(n+1)$, we use the sum until the $n$-th term and put the last one aside. The assertion follows by noting that $\sum_{i = 1}^{n} f(i)  = F(n)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$f(0)=1,f(n+1)=2f(n)$$

$$F(n)=\sum_{i=0}^n f(i)$$

---

### Simple proof without induction

Notice that $$f(n+1)=2f(n)=2(2f(n-1))=\cdots=2(2(\cdots2f(0)))=2^{n+1}$$

$$\implies f(n)=2^n$$

$$F(n)=\sum_{i=0}^n f(i)=\sum_{i=0}^n2^i=\frac{2^{n+1}-1}{1}=\boxed{f(n+1)-1}$$